# Wifi disconnecting often in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, networkmanager

Sometimes wifi disconnecting repeatedly. Sometime disconnecting after hours or after 30mins, i couldnt find the cause.
And sometimes when running `sudo docker exec -it 96414b09135d bash` also it disconnects after minutes.

i tried setting
`sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

```
wifi.powersave = 2
```

and tried

1. sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 down
2. sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
3. sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 up
4. sudo service network-manager restart

and tried

`systemctl list-unit-files --state enabled`

```
keyboard-setup.service                     enabled enabled      
ModemManager.service                       enabled enabled      
network-manager.service                    enabled enabled      
networkd-dispatcher.service                enabled enabled
```

Also tried,

`sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -D wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Failed to open config file '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf', error: No such file or directory
Failed to read or parse configuration '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf'.
```

Also tried `sudo nano /etc/NeworkManager/NetworkManger.conf`

```
    [device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Tried :

1. sudo service bluetooth restart
2. sudo modprobe wl sudo lshw -C network
3. sudo apt install network-manager
4. git clone https://github.com/mehedihshakeel/BroadcomInstaller2017.git
   git clone
   https://github.com/prasathlk/BroadcomInstaller2019.git cd
   BroadcomInstaller2019/      ./Broadcom.sh

Here `/etc/pm/sleep.d$ ls`

```
10_grub-common  10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate  config
```

Here `echo "options QCA9377 fwlps=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/QCA9377.conf`

```
options QCA9377 fwlps=N
```

Here `sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`
#timeout 300;

Here `dpkg -S $(which NetworkManager)`

```
network-manager: /usr/sbin/NetworkManager
```

Here is my `apt policy network-manager`

```
network-manager:
  Installed: 1.22.10-1ubuntu2.2
  Candidate: 1.22.10-1ubuntu2.2
  Version table:
 *** 1.22.10-1ubuntu2.2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.22.10-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Here are my `sudo journalctl -fu NetworkManager`

```
<info>  [1637549618.0666] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): state changed unknown -> bound
<warn>  [1637549996.3364] sup-iface[0x55dc05fec3d0,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
<info>  [1637549996.4370] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi now disabled by radio killswitch
<info>  [1637549996.4374] device (wlp2s0): state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<info>  [1637549996.4665] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
<info>  [1637549996.4666] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> done
<info>  [1637549996.4672] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
<info>  [1637549996.4672] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> done
---------------------
<warn>  [1637553729.6989] sup-iface[0x55dc05fec1f0,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
<info>  [1637553729.6992] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
<info>  [1637553729.6992] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
<info>  [1637553729.7093] device (wlp2s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<info>  [1637553729.7305] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
<info>  [1637553729.7306] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> done
<info>  [1637553729.7314] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
<info>  [1637553729.7314] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> done
---------------------
<warn>  [1637553946.7590] sup-iface[0x55dc05fec1f0,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
<info>  [1637553946.7982] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
<info>  [1637553946.7982] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
<info>  [1637553950.8662] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
<info>  [1637553950.8662] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
<warn>  [1637553962.0505] device (wlp2s0): link timed out.
<info>  [1637553962.0529] device (wlp2s0): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<warn>  [1637553962.0610] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'WIFINAME'
<info>  [1637553962.0650] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<info>  [1637553962.0985] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
<info>  [1637553962.0986] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> done
<info>  [1637553962.1123] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
<info>  [1637553980.3890] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set disabled
<info>  [1637553980.3891] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unavailable (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<info>  [1637553980.3930] audit: op="radio-control" arg="wireless-enabled" pid=1512 uid=1000 result="success"
<info>  [1637553980.3934] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unavailable (reason 'supplicant-failed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<info>  [1637553980.3962] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi now disabled by radio killswitch
<info>  [1637553984.3856] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
<info>  [1637553984.6532] audit: op="radio-control" arg="wireless-enabled" pid=1512 uid=1000 result="success"
<info>  [1637553984.6538] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi now enabled by radio killswitch
<info>  [1637553984.8032] sup-iface[0x55dc05fec100,wlp2s0]: supports 5 scan SSIDs
<info>  [1637553984.8048] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
<info>  [1637553984.8049] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
<info>  [1637553984.8055] device (wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

Answer (score 0):

have you found a solution? You may take a look at this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230140/wifi-keeps-dropping-out-ubuntu-20-04-and-broadcom-wireless-adaptor.
Please let me know if it helps.